How can I input user data in c++ so that the upcoming data will also be seen before user input?
I am creating simple library project and I created console menu. Here is what it displays.

So I want to make it so that if I input username then It will ask me to input user password but it should be so that the dashes should appear all at once not like waiting my input and that appear.

C++ doesn't have anything that does this built in. Your options are to write your own console IO library or use one that already exists like ncurses.

Link to the man page of the above suggestion.

Good job by the way. Doing that by hand definitely wasn’t an easy feat. I hope it is responsive though because that’s also important.

What you are asking for is not possible in standard C++. You will therefore have to revert to platform-specific functionality. Which operating system are you using? Linux, Microsoft Windows or MacOS? There probably are solutions for all operating systems, but they are not necessarily be the same.

I am using Mac operating system and Clion ide

@Abdulaxad: I have no experience with MacOS, but since it is Linux-based, I assume that Linux solutions will also work with it. Therefore, as previously suggested by someone else, you may want to take a look at the ncurses library.
